# Converting string declaration to member in a trait

Tags: php, laravel

I have a trait titled 'DeltaBody'. The trait is used in some Models and it works logic wise. However in the trait part of the code looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;
trait DeltaBody{
    public function getSafeCaption(){
        if($this->richCheck()){
            return $this->deltaToText();
        }else{
            return $this->body;
        }
    }
```

Now notice:

```
$this->body
```

For now this is ok, since this trait is on my Post and Comments model. By chance both of them have a database column 'body'. Say I introduce another Model in the future and instead of 'body' I have 'content'. Now I can't use my trait because it  references :

```
$this->body
```

So I wanted to change that into something that I can override.

Is there a way for me to say create a declaration in my trait:

```
var bodyName = 'body';
```

And then somehow override or set bodyName in the trait to 'content' within my Model after I use DeltaBody;?

So that the code in trait would be

```
$this->bodyName //calls $this->content since bodyName is set to 'content'?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your trait a little more reusable between potential unrelated objects, in your case models, you need to ensure the methods are defined within the trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait DeltaBody
{
    public function getSafeCaption()
    {
        if ($this->richCheck()) {
            return $this->deltaToText();
        } else {
            return $this->getContent();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make sure your model defines this method
     */
    abstract protected function deltaToText();

    /**
     * Make sure your model defines this method
     */
    abstract protected function richCheck();

    /**
     * Let the model decide which property to use(body, content)
     */
    abstract protected function getContent();
}
```

**Edit:** I made the assumption that `richCheck` and `deltaToText` did **not** exist inside the trait, if they do then just omit those.

An alternative you might be able to use if you don't wish to define `getContent` in every model is to define a property in every model, assuming PHP 7:

```
trait DeltaBody
{
    protected $bodyPropertyName = 'body';

    public function getSafeCaption()
    {
        if ($this->richCheck()) {
            return $this->deltaToText();
        } else {
            return $this->{$bodyPropertyName} ?? null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your model(s):

```
class ModelA
{
    use DeltaBody;

    protected $bodyPropertyName = 'body';
}

class ModelB
{
    use DeltaBody;

    protected $bodyPropertyName = 'content';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This was my thought too, but then I would have to actually implement those 3 functions in every Model that uses the trait. The logic of deltaToText(), richCheck(), and getContents(); is all constant, except for them calling $this->body.

Comment: Yes thats right. You are using the methods in the trait anyway, so might as well define them.

Comment: Just edited my comment before you responded. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems counter intuitive does it not? If I implement those 3 methods for the models that use the trait, I literally have to just copy and paste the entire contents of those functions and only change $this->body to $this->content or vice versa.

Comment: @Ash The purpose of defining these methods is to ensure you are able to call these methods. Lets assume we don't declare the abstract methods and you include this trait inside a model that does not have these methods defined, you'll end up with a `Call to undefined method`. Now, I assumed by the code you posted that `richText` and `deltaToText` does not exist in the trait, is this correct?

Comment: The `richText` and `deltaToText` do exist and are defined in the trait. But each of the functions have `$this->body` present in them. I posted the full trait on a pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/G5d2YtmE)

Comment: @Ash I have added an alternate solution, see if that makes sense.

Comment: This is perfect and works with my build, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.